# is this how the static-polymorphism works for variables in java

Tags: java, polymorphism

i want to make sure that my understanding is correct in static-polymorphism

please look at the code below

```
class a {        
   int x=0;    
}

class b extends a {        
   int x=4;    
}              

public class main4 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a f = new b();
        System.out.println(f.x);        
        b ff = new b();
        System.out.println(ff.x);
    }
}
```

the output is

```
0

4
```

does that happened because the compiler looks at the declared  type of the reference and upon that determines which x to print at compile time ??

(f is declared as type a, the compiler looks at f.x and decides it means a.x)??

& if so,is this called a static-polymorphism or hiding or what ??

thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code properly. As of now, your code is unreadable.

Comment: You didn't notice anything off with your formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymorphism is like looking on the object via the key hole. You don't see the whole object but only that it's part which corresponds to the type of variable you have assigned a reference to the object to.

The object can be seen as different "shapes/forms" - it depends what the key hole you are looking through. But it is still the same object in computer's memory. The form you can see depends on the type of variable you have assigned the object to.

Polymorphism is a multi-form of seeing same object.

If you have object created by `new b()` - you'll see it as a `b` class representant when you assign this object to the variable of type `b`. And you'll see it as a `a` class representant when you assign it to the variable of type `a`.
But it is still the same object. And... you can cast it between variables:

`f = (a)ff;`

and you'll see that suddenly the same object is seen as an representative of `a` class (including visibility of `x` field belonging to the `a` class).

Comment: i just realize that my code above is just a casting is this true ??

Comment: Not exactly because you have two separate objects (you've called `new` two times). But these objects are exactly the same. You're only looking at them in  different ways. And you still have an ability to cast them (their references) to the needed data type when assigning to variables of different types. This casting causes no loss of unvisible in particular case data.

Comment: i mean when i declared f as a

Comment: Yes - you still have an object of class `b`. But by assigning it to the variable of type `a` you limited the visibility of properties of the object only to those properties which are declared in type `a`. But the object is still whole object of class `b` in the computer's memory.

Comment: And you can write `b fff = (b)f;` (cast object `f` of type `a` to the type `b`) and it will work - you'll see `4` int the output after displaying it. Because by all the time there is object of class `b` in the memory. It's because you wrote `... = new b();` when you created that object.

Comment: And one side issue - please entitle classes with names beginning with capitalized character. Like `A` and `B` or `MyClass`. Variables and fields entitle with names beginning with lowercase characters like `f` and `ff` or `myVariable`. It is commonly used practice called UpperCamelCase :)

Comment: yes,i've tried that the thing is i was learning the difference between hiding & overriding & i forgot about the casting, just to make sure can i call the above code polymorphism or not

Comment: You can override methods but you cannot override fields.